# DataContract serialization of circular references works too deep for the first item of collection and too finely for the rest

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontract

I have two classes which refer on each other:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Student
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    public Student()
    {
        Courses = new List<Course>();
    }
}


[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Course
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public Course()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }
}
```

I want to serialize 4 Student entities, each of them has some courses attached.  after serialization only the first Student entity appears not empty. What is more, it has too many reference levels. And all others Student entities are empty:

```
<GetStudentsResult         
xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService2" 
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<a:Student xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" 
z:Id="i1">
<a:Courses>
<a:Course z:Id="i2">
<a:Id>1</a:Id>
<a:Name>Operation Systems</a:Name>
<a:Students>
<a:Student z:Ref="i1"/>
<a:Student z:Id="i3">
<a:Courses>
<a:Course z:Ref="i2"/>
<a:Course z:Id="i4">
<a:Id>2</a:Id>
<a:Name>Algorithmes and data structures</a:Name>
<a:Students>
<a:Student z:Ref="i3"/>
<a:Student z:Id="i5">
<a:Courses>
<a:Course z:Ref="i4"/>
<a:Course z:Id="i6">
<a:Id>3</a:Id>
<a:Name>Basics of HTML and CSS</a:Name>
<a:Students>
<a:Student z:Ref="i1"/>
<a:Student z:Id="i7">
<a:Courses>
<a:Course z:Ref="i2"/>
<a:Course z:Ref="i6"/>
</a:Courses>
<a:Id>3</a:Id>
<a:Name>Oleg</a:Name>
<a:Surname>Kuznetsov</a:Surname>
</a:Student>
<a:Student z:Ref="i5"/>
</a:Students>
</a:Course>
</a:Courses>
<a:Id>4</a:Id>
<a:Name>Olga</a:Name>
<a:Surname>Petrova</a:Surname>
</a:Student>
</a:Students>
</a:Course>
</a:Courses>
<a:Id>2</a:Id>
<a:Name>Maria</a:Name>
<a:Surname>Vasilyeva</a:Surname>
</a:Student>
<a:Student z:Ref="i7"/>
</a:Students>
</a:Course>
<a:Course z:Ref="i6"/>
</a:Courses>
<a:Id>1</a:Id>
<a:Name>Egor</a:Name>
<a:Surname>Ivanov</a:Surname>
</a:Student>
<a:Student xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"
z:Ref="i3"/>
<a:Student xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"     
z:Ref="i7"/>
<a:Student xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"     
z:Ref="i5"/>
</GetStudentsResult>
```

Here is my code, filling Student and Course collections:

```
Student s1 = new Student { Id = 1, Name = "Egor", Surname = "Ivanov" };
        Student s2 = new Student { Id = 2, Name = "Maria", Surname = "Vasilyeva" };
        Student s3 = new Student { Id = 3, Name = "Oleg", Surname = "Kuznetsov" };
        Student s4 = new Student { Id = 4, Name = "Olga", Surname = "Petrova" };

        context.Students.Add(s1);
        context.Students.Add(s2);
        context.Students.Add(s3);
        context.Students.Add(s4);

        Course c1 = new Course
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Operation Systems",
            Students = new List<Student>() { s1, s2, s3 }
        };
        Course c2 = new Course
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Algorithmes and data structures",
            Students = new List<Student>() { s2, s4 }
        };
        Course c3 = new Course
        {
            Id = 3,
            Name = "Basics of HTML and CSS",
            Students = new List<Student>() { s3, s4, s1 }
        };

        context.Courses.Add(c1);
        context.Courses.Add(c2);
        context.Courses.Add(c3);
```

Please advise.

Comment: Can you share the code that produces the `GetStudentsResult` that you are serializing here?  I assume it's an artificial test case?

Comment: Done. Yes, it's an artificial script

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is not a bug.  The [`IsReference = true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh241056.aspx) functionality of the data contract serializers *never creates [forward declarations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)* in the XML file, only backwards references.  Let's take a simple case:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true, Namespace="")]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Item SubItem { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public static void TestSimple()
    {
        var item1 = new Item { Id = 1 };
        var item2 = new Item { Id = 2 };
        item1.SubItem = item2;

        var xml = DataContractSerializerHelper.GetXml(new[] { item1, item2 });

        Debug.WriteLine(xml);
    }
}
```

The XML created by this test case is looks like:

```
<ArrayOfItem xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Item z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
        <Id>1</Id>
        <SubItem z:Id="i2">
            <Id>2</Id>
            <SubItem i:nil="true" />
        </SubItem>
    </Item>
    <Item z:Ref="i2" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
</ArrayOfItem>
```

What this means is:

- The *first* time item1 is encountered is in the root list.  It gets assigned a reference id `z:Id="i1"`
- The *first* time item2 is encountered is as a *child of item1*.  It gets assigned a reference id `z:Id="i2"`
- The *second* time item2 is encountered is in the root list.  In that case, it appears only as an indirect reference `z:Id="i2"`.

I.e., when serializing, the *first* time the data contract serializer encounters a reference object, it assigns it a reference id, saves that id in a dictionary, and proceeds to serialize the object.  Then, on subsequent encounters, it serializes a reference to that id, and nothing else.  Then, when deserializing, it does the reverse: when a reference id is encountered as an attribute of an element, the object created for that element is put in a dictionary, then is deserialized.  On subsequent encounters to that id, the saved object is taken from the dictionary and inserted in the object graph.

This simple one-pass algorithm does not allow for forward declarations.

It appears that you would prefer that reference objects be serialized at the highest possible level in the XML with forwards or backwards references inserted as needed in nested elements, like so:

```
<ArrayOfItem xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Item z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
        <Id>1</Id>
        <SubItem z:Ref="i2"/> <!-- FORWARD DECLARATION OF z:Id="i2" -->
    </Item>
    <Item z:Id="i2" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
        <Id>2</Id>
        <SubItem i:nil="true" />
    </Item>
</ArrayOfItem>
```

Unfortunately, the data contact serializer doesn't do that.

You can see that, by *indenting* your XML, all students are properly included -- all but the first as nested elements of the list of courses of the first student.  Then subsequent occurrences are just references:

```
<GetStudentsResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService2" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <a:Student xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" z:Id="i1">
      <a:Courses>
         <a:Course z:Id="i2">
            <a:Id>1</a:Id>
            <a:Name>Operation Systems</a:Name>
            <a:Students>
               <a:Student z:Ref="i1" />
               <a:Student z:Id="i3">
                  <a:Courses>
                     <a:Course z:Ref="i2" />
                     <a:Course z:Id="i4">
                        <a:Id>2</a:Id>
                        <a:Name>Algorithmes and data structures</a:Name>
                        <a:Students>
                           <a:Student z:Ref="i3" />
                           <a:Student z:Id="i5">
                              <a:Courses>
                                 <a:Course z:Ref="i4" />
                                 <a:Course z:Id="i6">
                                    <a:Id>3</a:Id>
                                    <a:Name>Basics of HTML and CSS</a:Name>
                                    <a:Students>
                                       <a:Student z:Ref="i1" />
                                       <a:Student z:Id="i7">
                                          <a:Courses>
                                             <a:Course z:Ref="i2" />
                                             <a:Course z:Ref="i6" />
                                          </a:Courses>
                                          <a:Id>3</a:Id>
                                          <a:Name>Oleg</a:Name>
                                          <a:Surname>Kuznetsov</a:Surname>
                                       </a:Student>
                                       <a:Student z:Ref="i5" />
                                    </a:Students>
                                 </a:Course>
                              </a:Courses>
                              <a:Id>4</a:Id>
                              <a:Name>Olga</a:Name>
                              <a:Surname>Petrova</a:Surname>
                           </a:Student>
                        </a:Students>
                     </a:Course>
                  </a:Courses>
                  <a:Id>2</a:Id>
                  <a:Name>Maria</a:Name>
                  <a:Surname>Vasilyeva</a:Surname>
               </a:Student>
               <a:Student z:Ref="i7" />
            </a:Students>
         </a:Course>
         <a:Course z:Ref="i6" />
      </a:Courses>
      <a:Id>1</a:Id>
      <a:Name>Egor</a:Name>
      <a:Surname>Ivanov</a:Surname>
   </a:Student>
   <a:Student xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" z:Ref="i3" />
   <a:Student xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" z:Ref="i7" />
   <a:Student xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" z:Ref="i5" />
</GetStudentsResult>
```

If you deserialize that XML with `DataContractSerializer`, you will find your graph of students and courses correctly restored with the same topology as the original graph.

Comment: Thanks, do You know how should I modify deserialization method in Web Reference client part?

Comment: If you have the same `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` on the client classes it should just work.  Is that not happening?

Comment: Client classes are generated automatically in reference.cs, and it doesn't contain this attribute. It is strange that server has DataContract Serialization, but client has XML deserialization even taking into account that it's classes are generated using server.

Comment: @RomanPrykhodko - I'm not sure why the automatic classes are lacking this on your side -- it's not easy for me to try to reproduce it here at home.  The .xsd files created by `scvutil.exe` certainly contain the requisite elements.  I suggest asking another question specifically about why this is happening, e.g. "IsReference=true is missing from classes generated with 'Add Service Reference`", with specifics about how to reproduce the problem.